# How To Speed Up This Pandas Operation (Group By Nested List Item)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following `df`:

```
   col1  col2    col3
0     1     3    brazil argentina spain uk
1     2     4    brazil france iceland
2     7     9    iceland brazil
3     8     1    chile
4     5     0    spain italy
```

I can get a list of unique word themes in `col3` by creating a set:

```
split_list = []
for i in df['col3'].to_list()
    themes = i.split(' ')
    for j in themes:
        split_list.append(j)
unique_themes = list(set(split_list))
```

Which provides the following:

```
unique_themes = ['brazil', 'argentina', 'spain', 'uk', 'france', 'iceland', 'chile', 'italy']
```

I can then create new dataframe which provides a sum of `col1` and `col2` for each theme in `unique_themes`:

```
theme_df = pd.DataFrame()

columns = df.columns.tolist()
columns.remove('col3')

for theme in unique_themes:

    data = df[df['col3'].apply(lambda x: theme in x.split(' '))][columns]
    data["theme"] = theme
    data["count"] = 1
    theme_df = pd.concat([theme_df, data], axis=0)

data = theme_df.groupby("theme", as_index=False)[["theme"] + ["count"] + columns].sum()
```

Which gives the following `theme_df`:

```
      theme      count   col1   col2
0     brazil         3     10     16 
1     argentina      1      1      3
2     spain          2      6      3
3     uk             1      1      3
4     france         1      2      4
5     iceland        2      9     13
6     chile          1      8      1
7     italy          1      5      0
```

However this is very slow. On a dataframe of 15,000 rows, with approx 5,000 unique word themes, the `for` loop (which checks to see if the `theme` is included in `col3`) takes approx 2 minutes to calculate.

Is there a better (faster) way of doing this? Perhaps normalising the data first, so that `col3` only contains a single theme, removing the need for `apply`? Or another approach altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for repeat values converted to lists by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then aggregate by names aggregations with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(col3 = df['col3'].str.split())
         .explode('col3')
         .groupby('col3', sort=False)
         .agg(count=('col1','size'),
              col1=('col1','sum'),
              col2=('col2','sum'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
        col3  count  col1  col2
0     brazil      3    10    16
1  argentina      1     1     3
2      spain      2     6     3
3         uk      1     1     3
4     france      1     2     4
5    iceland      2     9    13
6      chile      1     8     1
7      italy      1     5     0
```

EDIT: You can create dictionary of tuples dynamically, add first key for counts and pass with `**` to `agg`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['col3'])
d = {c: (c,'sum') for c in cols}
#merge dictionaries
d = {**{'count': (cols[0],'size')}, **d}
print (d)
{'count': ('col1', 'size'), 'col1': ('col1', 'sum'), 'col2': ('col2', 'sum')}

df1 = (df.assign(col3 = df['col3'].str.split())
        .explode('col3')
        .groupby('col3', sort=False)
        .agg(**d)
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
        col3  count  col1  col2
0     brazil      3    10    16
1  argentina      1     1     3
2      spain      2     6     3
3         uk      1     1     3
4     france      1     2     4
5    iceland      2     9    13
6      chile      1     8     1
7      italy      1     5     0
```

Comment: Instead of just `col1` and `col2`, suppose I have an unknown number of columns which I want to aggregate using `sum`. Do I need to specify each column and aggregation method (e.g. sum) individually as keyword arguments in the `agg` function? Or can I just remove `col3` from the list of columns, for example `columns = df.columns.tolist().remove('col3')`, then pass this list to the `agg` function, and all data columns will be summed?

Comment: 790x faster than my method. On a datset of 15,000 rows, the whole process took 0.097s to calculate instead of 76.724s :)